# is it correct to use a Pearson correlation test on transformed data (log, boxcox)

Tags: r, correlation, data-transformation, pearson-r

I am trying to study the correlation between 2 variables non-normally distributed. These are the values (n. 134) of measured level of a substance (bisphenol A) in urine in mothers and relative newborns: `bpaTm` (Bisphenol A Total Mother) and `bpaTn` (Bisphenol A Total Newborn) (see supplementary at the bottom for the original variables). Here their distribution plot:

`bpaTm` distribution:
[image]

`bpaTn` distribution:
[image]

These are not normalized neither by `log()` nor `boxcox()` transformation (see supplementary data at the bottom for their distribution after transformation and `boxcox()` transformation meaning). But the values of Pearson correlation test changes with the transformation (I guess variables are getting more "linearly" correlated):

```
> cor.test( db0$bpaTm, db0$bpaTn )

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  db0$bpaTm and db0$bpaTn
t = 0.077775, df = 132, p-value = 0.9381
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1630063  0.1761554
sample estimates:
        cor 
0.006769264 

> 
> cor.test( log(db0$bpaTm), log(db0$bpaTn) )

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  log(db0$bpaTm) and log(db0$bpaTn)
t = -1.5421, df = 132, p-value = 0.1254
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.29593959  0.03740469
sample estimates:
       cor 
-0.1330276 

> 
> cor.test( boxcox_transform(db0$bpaTm), boxcox_transform(db0$bpaTn) )

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  boxcox_transform(db0$bpaTm) and boxcox_transform(db0$bpaTn)
t = 34.013, df = 132, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.9267169 0.9623740
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.9474099
```

my question is: it is correct to apply a Pearson correlation on such transformed data? Or there are some kind of theoretical errors in this transformation?

PS: I know I can use Spearman and Kendall's tau in order to have a rank comparison not influenced by transformation, but I would like to understand the "correctness" of transformations over the Pearson correlation that is influenced by these transformations

**SUPPLEMENTARY DATA:**

Here the plot of the tranformed variables:

`log(bpaTm)` distribution:
[image]
`log(bpaTn)` distribution:
[image]
`boxcox_transform(bpaTm)` distribution:
[image]
`boxcox_transform(bpaTn)` distribution:
[image]

and here the variables data:

```
> dput( db0$bpaTm )
c(0.0801, 0.0062, 0.0445, 0.0033, 0.1039, 0.1584, 0.0426, 0.004, 
0.1322, 0.0021, 0.0773, 1.0562, 0.0303, 0.0429, 0.6408, 0.2638, 
0.0065, 2.7172, 0.1071, 0.2451, 0.3235, 0.0547, 0.084, 0.3314, 
0.0079, 0.004, 0.0027, 0.0996, 0.0022, 0.6869, 2.3778, 0.3234, 
0.0977, 0.0798, 0.5955, 0.2373, 2.7369, 0.0179, 0.4769, 0.8089, 
0.1191, 0.4511, 0.1964, 0.0025, 0.0034, 0.002, 0.0362, 0.1084, 
0.0814, 0.0052, 0.1043, 0.0055, 8e-04, 0.0062, 0.0026, 0.0034, 
0.0044, 1.1179, 0.0029, 0.0018, 0.002, 0.7946, 0.0337, 0.0914, 
0.0793, 0.0026, 0.0037, 0.0015, 0.011, 0.0201, 0.0064, 0.077, 
0.7026, 0.708, 0.3732, 0.0092, 0.7062, 0.3412, 0.2587, 0.0049, 
0.2711, 0.4696, 0.2196, 0.5888, 0.2751, 0.0057, 0.3905, 0.7022, 
0.0049, 0.5612, 0.0014, 0.0013, 0.3752, 0.349, 0.0011, 0.0138, 
1.4973, 0.2776, 0.4582, 0.0072, 0.5075, 0.0022, 0.7452, 0.2239, 
0.8222, 0.1791, 0.4244, 0.0042, 0.007, 0.085, 0.3591, 0.9713, 
7e-04, 0.0066, 0.2405, 0.0013, 0.2325, 0.6365, 0.0027, 0.3721, 
0.0045, 0.0046, 0.1868, 0.3672, 0.0018, 0.0718, 0.0727, 0.0446, 
0.1136, 0.0283, 0.1102, 0.1274, 0.0261, 0.0844)

c(0.1273, 0.01858, 0.02705, 0.02037, 0.84932, 0.02425, 0.42594, 
0.11851, 0.23176, 0.55762, 0.022, 0.01888, 0.02659, 0.02928, 
0.05532, 0.03981, 0.27789, 2.07942, 0.01527, 0.43818, 0.08772, 
0.01087, 0.49211, 0.01918, 0.02688, 0.03996, 0.13425, 0.03981, 
0.23498, 0.14297, 1.40088, 0.01869, 0.09098, 0.66275, 0.0149, 
1.19778, 0.01913, 0.05903, 0.38875, 0.02282, 0.01389, 0.03707, 
0.03262, 0.08987, 0.01933, 0.02119, 0.14978, 0.03883, 0.30822, 
0.94456, 0.01933, 0.3146, 0.02581, 0.01678, 0.03177, 5.41625, 
0.01925, 0.20909, 0.54781, 0.26473, 0.03725, 0.05871, 0.02637, 
0.20771, 0.02161, 0.07835, 0.01947, 0.69323, 2.20418, 0.03079, 
0.83059, 0.01598, 0.02812, 0.02298, 0.02378, 0.74808, 0.05344, 
0.15396, 0.233, 0.14283, 0.0232, 0.40811, 0.16316, 0.09577, 0.52982, 
0.04868, 0.28942, 0.34124, 0.01783, 0.01883, 0.02244, 0.78543, 
0.16619, 0.01928, 0.3058, 3.39427, 0.17005, 0.02649, 0.05704, 
0.12563, 0.4699, 0.37497, 0.02692, 0.19658, 3.83661, 0.02296, 
0.58335, 0.03506, 3.00608, 0.01256, 0.03751, 0.02485, 0.73003, 
4.07519, 5.66704, 7.75299, 0.43675, 0.01065, 0.31909, 0.09174, 
0.02113, 0.0218, 0.02975, 0.0263, 1.90869, 0.01766, 0.05318, 
0.03136, 1.1696, 0.78481, 0.30664, 0.21008, 0.123, 1.34231)
```

`boxcox()` transformation is:

```
boxcox_transform <- function( var1 ) {
    Box = boxcox(var1 ~ 1,              # Transform as a single vector
                 lambda = seq(-6,6,0.1)      # Try values -6 to 6 by 0.1
                 )

    Cox = data.frame(Box$x, Box$y)            # Create a data frame with the results
    Cox2 = Cox[with(Cox, order(-Cox$Box.y)),] # Order the new data frame by decreasing y
#Cox2[1,]                                  # Display the lambda with the greatest log likelihood
lambda = Cox2[1, "Box.x"]                 # Extract that lambda
var1_box = (db0$bpsFn ^ lambda - 1)/lambda   # Transform the original data
    return(var1_box)
}
```

Here the scatter plots of the variables:

non transformed
[image]
log transformed
[image]
boxocox transformed
[image]

Comment: nice question, can you put the scatter plots as well?

Comment: @TPArrow edited with scatter plots, any idea? Thank you in advance

Comment: I do not see any difference between BC and log transformed scatterplots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do a correct analysis on empirically transformed variables you are compelled to account for model uncertainty when assessing the final correlation coefficient.  For example if you bootstrapped the whole process you'd see a lot of transformation uncertainty propagate into the confidence interval for the correlation coefficient.  See for example [The Cost of Data Analysis](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10618600.1992.10474582) by Faraway.

Far, far easier is to use a robust correlation index that not only does not assume a distribution for either variable, but does not need transformations (if they are monotonic) nor an assumption of linearity.  I'd just go with Spearman's $\rho$ here.  Use your time wisely.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, do you have the article PDF you cited? I cannot access it and I would love to read it

Comment: This looks like a preprint of the final paper: https://people.bath.ac.uk/jjf23/papers/cda.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I try to look at the problem from a different angle.

Here the data violates two fundamental assumptions of the Pearson `cor.test`,

1. Your variables should be approximately normally distributed
2. There should be no significant outliers

See [here](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/pearsons-product-moment-correlation-using-spss-statistics.php) for more details. Then `cor.test` result is not reliable for your data.

Coming back to the effect of transformations on the (linear) correlation. In this answer, I only explain `log` transformation and others could comment or improve.

Note that `log` is a monotone one-to-one transformation, as a result, the linear correlation should not change under this transformation. See below that we generate 10 linearly correlated observations.

```
set.seed(123456)
x = c(runif(10, 1, 2))
y = x * 2 + rnorm(10, sd = .1)
plot(x, y)
```

[image]

and

```
> cor(x,y)
[1] 0.9849312
> cor(log(x),log(y))
[1] 0.9822018
```

that shows no sign of significant change in the correlations. Now we add an outlier to this data,

```
set.seed(123456)
x = c(runif(10, 1, 2), 10)
y = c(head(x * 2 + rnorm(11, sd = .1), 10), 3)
plot(x, y)
```

[image]

The correlation coefficient of the raw and transformed data are listed below,

```
> cor(x, y)
[1] 0.1170776
> cor(log(x), log(y))
[1] 0.3400024
```

That shows some strong signals of the change in the correlation.

**Conclusion**: in your data, the `log` transformation acts toward reduces the effect of outliers (and shrinking the long tails of the distribution) and this improves the correlation coefficient.